# how to run Java applet in netbeans IDE without any main class

Tags: java, applet, netbeans-platform, netbeans-8.2

I just **imported a project from eclipse workspce to Netbeans IDE** and tried to run it.

But each time *an error "**Main Class not found**" was produced*.

Then, I ***enabled Webstart*** for my project and chose the **Applet class option**.

But the same problem continues....

**Is there a way to run Java applets without main class???**

> My project contains a Java Applet and a Java panel(which is used by the applet)
>   I want to run Japplet.java through netbeans....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a Main class if your (Netbeans) project is for a standalone application. If it's an Applet, you'll need to be provide an Applet class.
A Main class is any class that has the following method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ... any code to initialize your application
}
```

An applet class is a class that extends the Applet class. Applets run in webbrowsers, but are rarely used nowadays. Webstart is also a way to run Java-applications from webbrowsers but also rarely used.

I assume you 'just' want to run an application: I'd suggest to add the main method to one of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also **run it in netbeans**

**Right click -->*yourJavaApplet.java*--->Run File..**

Answer (score -1):

Try Running the *project in **Eclipse***

**Eclipse makes it easy to run Java applets.**

Just **Select *yourJavaApplet.java* or project and run it from toolbar.**
Or **right-click *yourJavaApplet.java* ---> Run As--->Java Applet**

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Wasted my whole day trying to do this in netbeans and just found an easy way in eclipse..By the way sorry for troubling..